# Want to show image , after getting image name using ajax, not want to return html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show image after getting response from ajax

I have following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title> Dashboard</title>
  <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                url = "<?php echo $_GET['PATH_INFO']; ?>";
                $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: 'http://localhost:8081/fetch_image',
                         dataType: "JSON",
                         data: {
                                external_source: url,

                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                                local_image= data[0]['local_source'];
                                alert(local_image);
                        }
                });

        });
    </script>
     </head>
<body>


</body>
```

I have no idea, how to show  local_image on success  of ajax Request

I need this in php  so it will return content type jpeg header

Comment: Just set src attribute of an image element and add it to the DOM, but i'm not sure what you mean by: `I need this in php` && `not want to return html`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your success-function add:

```
$(body).append('<img src="' + local_image + '">');
```

Comment: @HituBansal That doesn't make sense, so what you mean?

Comment: i need something like this ..<?php 
$image= "http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/18/us/HEART/HEART-tmagSF-v4.jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($image);
?>

Comment: @HituBansal images in browsers are nearly always displayed via `HTML`. and i guess you don't want to use `flash` or a `java applet` to show the image, or do you?

Comment: @HituBansal yes, like A. Wolff said: you can't generate `PHP` code with `javascript` since `PHP` is server-side and `javascript` is client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank image.

```
<img id="local_source" style="display:none"/>
```

In AJAX success function:

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#local_source").show().attr('local_source', data[0]['local_source']);
}
```